# How can I deal with PL-SQL package error PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the following: := )

Tags: oracle, plsql, package

There is a similar answer for the problem I have, but it seems that this answer is for procedure issue.
I supposed to make a pl sql package which has 3 procedures inside. It's gonna be like that:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Count_num AS
    PROCEDURE count_emps(dno IN number);
    PROCEDURE count_deps(empssn IN char(9));
    PROCEDURE delete_deps(empssn IN char(9), dname IN varchar2(15));
END;
/
show errors

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY Count_num AS

    PROCEDURE count_emps(dno IN number)
    AS
        cnt number;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt
        WHERE Department.dnumber = Employee.dno
        AND Department.dnumber = dno;

        dbms_output.put_line('Number of Employee is ' || cnt);
    END;

    PROCEDURE count_deps(empssn IN char(9))
    AS
        cnt2 number;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO cnt2
        WHERE Dependent.essn = Employee.ssn
        AND Department.essn = empssn;

        dbms_output.put_line('Number of dependent is ' || cnt2);
    END;

    PROCEDURE delete_deps(empssn IN char(9), dname IN varchar2(15))
    AS
    BEGIN
        DELETE *
        FROM Dependent
        WHERE Dependent.essn = Employee.ssn
        AND Dependent.essn = empssn
        AND Dependent.dependent_name = dname;

        SELECT *
        FROM Dependent
        WHERE Dependent.essn = Employee.ssn
        AND Dependent.essn = empssn
        AND Dependent.dependent_name = dname;
        END;
END;
/
show errors

EXEC Count_num.count_emps(5);
EXEC Count_num.count_deps('333445555');
EXEC Count_num.delete_deps('333445555', 'Alice')
show errors
```

count_emps counts the number of employees for a department, 
count_deps counts the number of dependents for a valid employee, 
delete_deps deletes a specific depdendent. It's creation query is like below:

```
drop table Employee cascade constraints;
commit;

create table Employee 
(
    fname varchar2(15),
    minit varchar2(1), -- can be char
    lname varchar2(15),
    ssn char(9),
    bdate date,
    address varchar2(50),
    sex varchar2(1)     CHECK(Sex = 'M' or Sex = 'F'),
    salary number, -- need to put check on salary 
    superssn char(9),
    dno number  DEFAULT 0,
    constraint EMPPK
        primary key(ssn),
    constraint EMPSUPERVRFK
        foreign key(superssn) references Employee(ssn)
            ON DELETE SET NULL
);

drop table Department cascade constraints;
commit;
create table Department 
(
    dname varchar2(15)  NOT NULL,
    dnumber number,
    mgr_ssn char(9)     DEFAULT '000000000',
    mgr_start_date date,
    constraint DEPTPK
        primary key(dnumber),
    constraint DEPTMGRFK
        foreign key(mgr_ssn) references Employee(ssn)
            ON DELETE SET NULL
);

drop table Dependent cascade constraints;
commit;
create table Dependent
(
    Essn char(9), 
    Dependent_name varchar2(15),
    Sex varchar2(15),
    Bdate date,
    Relationship varchar2(15),
    constraint DEPENDPK
        primary key (Essn, Dependent_name),
    constraint DEPENDFK
        foreign key(Essn) references Employee(Ssn)
);
```

When I execute package queries, it gives me an error like below:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Count_num AS
  2          PROCEDURE count_emps(dno IN number);
  3          PROCEDURE count_deps(empssn IN char(9));
  4          PROCEDURE delete_deps(empssn IN char(9), dname IN varchar2(15));
  5  END;
  6  /

Warning: Package created with compilation errors.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.02
SQL> show errors
Errors for PACKAGE COUNT_NUM:

LINE/COL ERROR                                                                                                          
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------                                              
3/37     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the                                                
         following:                                                                                                     
         := ) , default varying character large                                                                         
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.                                                           

4/38     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the                                                
         following:                                                                                                     
         := ) , default varying character large                                                                         
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.                                                           

4/60     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "(" when expecting one of the                                                

LINE/COL ERROR                                                                                                          
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------                                              
         following:                                                                                                     
         := . ) , @ % default character                                                                                 
         The symbol ":=" was substituted for "(" to continue.
```

I can't recognize what this error is, so anyone can explain what this error is, and how can I handle this issue?

Comment: data lengths cannot be defined for data types for procedures' or functions' parameters' such as `char(9)` or `varchar2(15)`, whereas should be just as `char` or `varchar2` .

Comment: Not directly related but you do not need to commit after ddl statements. Oracle internally issues them; actually 2, one before executing the ddl and one after the ddl.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the length specified for the data types in the arguments.
Also, better to specify the column data type than hard-coding it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE Count_num AS
          PROCEDURE count_emps(i_dno IN employee.dno%TYPE);
          PROCEDURE count_deps(i_empssn IN employee.ssn%TYPE);
          PROCEDURE delete_deps(i_empssn IN employee.ssn%TYPE, 
                                i_dname IN department.dname%TYPE
                               );
END;
/
```